# Why does ngRepeat add an empty option inside select

Tags: angularjs

Here's a Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vr3z4bxFmsiJPs1ye2Vd.

The `ngRepeat` directive adds an empty option at the top when `ngIf` is present on the first option element which is supposed to be default.

Is there anyway to avoid that?
I want to use `ngRepeat`, not `ngOptions`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` binds two-way, so you are trying to bind the selection to numbers instead of variables, and I don't know what exactly are you trying to do... but this is the cause of the problem

Comment: The numbers are the IDs for the dropdown options. It's a quickly made-up example.